# When writing to a file in Ruby why does it sometimes occur AFTER my next few lines of code?

Tags: ruby, file, loops, while-loop

I want to write to a file then immediately afterwards wait until some condition is met, sleeping 1-second between attempts. An example of what I'm trying to do would look like this:

```
thingsToGet = ["schwifty", "down", "low"]
writeFile = File.new("myfile.txt", "w")

thingsToGet.each do |element|
  writeFile.puts "#{element}"
  while #some condition is false
    sleep(1)
  end
  ### HERE for some reason is when writeFile gets written to
end
```

as you can see in the last comment, for some reason even though `writeFile.puts` comes before that while-loop that waits for a condition the actual writing only occurs AFTER the while loop is over.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2):

Actually `writeFile` is written after the file is closed, not after the `while` loop ends; and this happens because the file is saved **after** the stream is closed, so you won't be able to see any changes in the file before that.

I assume that you are closing the file later in your code, or it is being closed automatically after the program runs (although you **should** close it yourself), and that's why you see the file updated after the program ends.

If you want to see the file updated on each time you use `puts`, then you must close (and open) it every time in your loop; for example:

```
thingsToGet = ['schwifty', 'down', 'low']

thingsToGet.each do |element|
    File.open('myfile.txt', 'a') do |file|
      file.puts("#{element}")
    end

    while ##some condition is false
      sleep(1)
    end
    ### HERE for some reason is when writeFile gets written to
end
```

Two things to notice:

- `File.open` is being used with a block, so the file will close after the block is executed.
- The file is opened with `a` *open mode* which will **append** the text to it instead of deleting it every time it is opened (as it would if `w` is used).

Keep in mind that, opening and closing the file on every line you write to it, could cause performance issues in your program.